# How to get cursor position in a Edittext

Tags: android

I am making an Android application. In my application, I have to find the cursor position of a edittext. For example, I put the text `"how are you"` on edittext. If I click next to character `'a'` then, I have to find the cursor now in front of 'a'.

How can I find out the cursor position and the character where cursor is placed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `getSelectionStart()` method to get current position of cursor in an `Edittext`